# How to i get my last class element data-id?

Tags: jquery

html

```
<ul id="productCategory-ul" class="productCategory__ul">
<li></figure data-id="1"></figure></li>
<li></figure data-id="2"></figure></li>
<li></figure data-id="3"></figure></li>
<li></figure data-id="4"></figure></li>
</ul><!-- end of brandContent__ul -->
```

my intention is to get my last figure li data-id , but i tried some code and it didt work.

```
<li></figure data-id="4"></figure></li>
```

my code

1.

```
var lastProductItem  = $("#productCategory-ul li figure:last-child").attr("data-id");
```

2.

```
var lastProductItem = $("#productCategory-ul  > li figure:last-child").data("id");
```

so how do i get my productCategory-ul last data-id ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First correct the *HTML*

```
<li><figure data-id="4"></figure></li>
```

instead of

```
<li></figure data-id="4"></figure></li>
```

As you intent to target the last `li` element, use `:last-child` selector with it. then you can get descendant `figure` afterwards `id` can be fetched.

```
var lastProductItem = $("#productCategory-ul  li:last-child figure").data("id");
```

```js
console.log($("#productCategory-ul  li:last-child figure").data("id"))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="productCategory-ul" class="productCategory__ul">
  <li>
    <figure data-id="1">1</figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure data-id="2">2</figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure data-id="3">3</figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure data-id="4">4</figure>
  </li>
</ul>
<!-- end of brandContent__ul -->
```

Comment: Just a word of warning: `:last-child` works here, but if you just wanted the last of a list of elements and the last of them *wasn't* the last child in the parent (e.g., a different kind of element followed it), `:last-child` wouldn't be what you'd want. You'd want jQuery's `:last` CSS extension, or `.last`.

Answer (score 0):

### HTML

```
<ul id="productCategory-ul" class="productCategory__ul">
<li><figure data-id="1"></figure></li>
<li><figure data-id="2"></figure></li>
<li><figure data-id="3"></figure></li>
<li><figure data-id="4"></figure></li>
</ul><!-- end of brandContent__ul -->
```

### Jquery

```
var lastProductItem = $("#productCategory-ul  > li:last-child figure").attr("data-id");
alert(lastProductItem);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can play with last item like this

```
    $( "ul li:last-child" ).css({ color:"red", fontSize:"80%" }) .hover(function() {
    $( this ).addClass( "solast" );
  }, function() {
    $( this ).removeClass( "solast" );
  });
```