# How do I find the last element with a specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML

```
<ul id="productCategory-ul" class="productCategory__ul">
<li><figure class="productCategory__ul__li" data-id="1"></figure></li>
<li><figure class="productCategory__ul__li" data-id="2"></figure></li>
<li><figure class="productCategory__ul__li" data-id="3"></figure></li>
<li><figure class="productCategory__ul__li" data-id="4"></figure></li>
</ul><!-- end of brandContent__ul -->
```

My intention is to get the last `<li>`'s figure `data-id`.

```
<li><figure class="productCategory__ul__li" data-id="4"></figure></li>
```

How do I get `productCategory__ul__li` last `data-id`?

I don't want to use `productCategory-ul` to find my last `li`, I wanted to use `$each` or use `productCategory__ul__li` to find it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to i get my last class element data-id?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41427762/how-to-i-get-my-last-class-element-data-id)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bear in mind that jQuery is simply a javascript library.

The point of the jQuery library is *"write less, do more"* - it is intended to help you achieve a great deal by writing only short snippets of code.

For something like this, you *could* write this in jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var jQueryLastDataID = $('.productCategory__ul__li:last').attr('data-id');
});
```

Though, arguably, it would barely take any longer to write this in plain javascript:

```
var dataIds = document.querySelectorAll('.productCategory__ul__li');
var javascriptLastDataID = dataIds[(dataIds.length - 1)].dataset.id;
```

**Working example:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var jQueryLastDataID = $('.productCategory__ul__li:last').attr('data-id');
    console.log('jQueryLastDataID is ' + jQueryLastDataID);
});

var dataIds = document.querySelectorAll('.productCategory__ul__li');
var javascriptLastDataID = dataIds[(dataIds.length - 1)].dataset.id;
console.log('javascriptLastDataID is ' + javascriptLastDataID);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="productCategory-ul" class="productCategory__ul">
<li><figure class="productCategory__ul__li" data-id="1"></figure></li>
<li><figure class="productCategory__ul__li" data-id="2"></figure></li>
<li><figure class="productCategory__ul__li" data-id="3"></figure></li>
<li><figure class="productCategory__ul__li" data-id="4"></figure></li>
</ul><!-- end of brandContent__ul -->
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `:last` selector (or the `last()` method) to retrieve the last element in a matched set:

```
var id = $('.productCategory__ul__li:last').data('id');
   // or $('.productCategory__ul__li').last().data('id');
```

```js
var id = $('.productCategory__ul__li:last').data('id');
console.log(id);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="productCategory-ul" class="productCategory__ul">
  <li>
    <figure class="productCategory__ul__li" data-id="1">id = 1</figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure class="productCategory__ul__li" data-id="2">id = 2</figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure class="productCategory__ul__li" data-id="3">id = 3</figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure class="productCategory__ul__li" data-id="4">id = 4</figure>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the last child of li's.

```
$('.productCategory__ul__li:last-child')
```

Answer (score 0):

You may do:

```
jQuery(".productCategory__ul__li").last().data("id");
```

There is no need to go for `each` or use `ul`. This code `jQuery(".productCategory__ul__li")` selects all the elements with the given class.

`last()` would select the last element from the element's array.

**data** would pick up the data attributes(here `id`).

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){

            $( ".productCategory__ul__li" ).last().addClass( "lastButNotTheLeast" );

     });
```

Hope it helps!